# Retrieve data from Multiple table From Ms access

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I make two table one is **exp_detail** and 2nd is **exp_head**.

- **exp_detail** Table contain exp_id,Amount_paid,sr_no and exp_Description **column**
- **exp_head** table contain exp_id and exp_Name **column**

Now I am using this query to retrieve data from **exp_detail** table. This will display correctly. This query is

```
select sr_no, e_date, e_paid, e_des 
from exp_detail 
where e_date = #" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date + 
"# order by exp_detail.sr_no"
```

But problem is this I retrieve `exp_Name` using the primary key and foreign key from `exp_head` table in this above given query. How it is possible?

Comment: Can you add your C# code along with some sample data from each of your tables to help demonstrate your issue?  Your SQL actually looks like native Access SQL.  If you are using C#/OLE, you can use more native SQL (including Parameters) to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use SQL Joins to join both the tables. Refer the below updated sql statement with the join statement, i.e. 3rd line

```
select sr_no, e_date, e_paid, e_des 
  from exp_detail 
 inner join exp_head on exp_detail.exp_id = exp_head.exp_id --This is added--
 where e_date=#" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date + "# 
 order by exp_detail.sr_no
```

Comment: clsCon.list_DataView("select sr_no, e_date,exp_name,e_paid, e_des  from exp_detail inner join exp_head on exp_detail.exp_id = exp_head.exp_id where e_date=#" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date + "# order by exp_detail.sr_no", this.lstv_ExpDetail);

Comment: clsCon.list_DataView("select sr_no, e_date,exp_name,e_paid, e_des  from exp_detail inner join exp_head on exp_detail.exp_id = exp_head.exp_id where e_date=#" + this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date + "# order by exp_detail.sr_no", this.lstv_ExpDetail);  Error is No value give for one or mora parameter

Comment: @mr.cool Are you providing the value for `this.dp_expDetail.Value.Date`?. Keep this sql statement in a separate string variable, and then use it in the dataview, and check the value being derived using the debug mode. Also as mentioned by @hambone it would be helpful if you could provide the C# code also

Comment: Yes I provide value.... and in this link u seen code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041794/retvering-data-from-multiple-tables-and-display-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment57809155_35041794